# How to use decorator to bind a argument to a staticmethod function?

Tags: python, static-methods, python-decorators

My problem is look like below:

```
class foo(obj):

    def __init__(self, st='123'):
       self.st = st

    def process(self, x):
       self.st += x

    @staticmethod
    def do_foo(x, myfoo=None):
        if myfoo is None:
           myfoo = foo()
        myfoo.process(x)

def wrapper(fn, st):

    foo_func = foo(st)
    foo.do_foo = functools.partial(foo.do_foo, myfoo=foo_func)
    fn()
    print foo_func.st

    return wrap

@wrapper('stst')
def pro():
    foo.do_foo('double')

def pro2():
    foo.do_foo('double')

pro2()   # <--- normal foo.do_foo
pro()    # <--- partialed foo.do_foo
pro2()   # <--- partialed foo.do_foo
```

I want to create `wrapper` decorator to wrapper the staticmethod `foo.do_foo` with customize `foo` class, and after the `pro()` executed, this decorator be able to across the foo object to do some job. ie save the variable value.

How every, in upper code, the wrapper change the `foo.do_foo` forever globally, not just change it in the decorator scope.

So how to just let `foo.do_foo` only changed in the decorator scope not global?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an slightly different answer based on the [gist.github.com code](https://gist.github.com/tywtyw2002/c885bd917430e0563288) linked to in your comment (which appears to be based on the first version of my answer).

As I said initially, it sounds to me like what you need to do is make `wrapper()` a *decorator factory* function rather than a decorator itself — in other words make it a function that creates and returns a decorator based on its argument(s).

As mentioned in my response to your comment, the problem is that `Prof.do` staticmethod is essentially a global variable, and if the wrapped function changes it, this will affect all subsequent calls to it — which is the root cause of your problem.

A workaround is to make the `wrapped()` function the decorator creates save the value of `Prof.do` before calling the decorated function, and then restore it afterward, so the changes only affect calls to the function made though it. This prevents what it does to `Prof.do` from messing up other calls to it in other wrapped functions that may be created. It also prevents the accumulation of their effects.

I've encapsulated the changing and restoring the staticmethod by putting it in a [contextmanager](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html?highlight=contextmanager#contextlib.contextmanager) helper function. One downside of needing to do this is that it increases the amount of overhead involved to make calls to the wrapped function.

```
import contextlib
import functools

class Prof(object):
    def __init__(self, p='s'):
        self.p = p

    @staticmethod
    def do(x, obj=None):
        if obj is None:
            obj = Prof()
        obj.dprint(x)
        print

    def dprint(self, x):
        print self.p, x
        self.p += x

def wrapper(st):
    @contextlib.contextmanager
    def prof_context(obj):  # could also be defined outside of wrapper function
        # save current staticmethod and replace it with partial below
        saved_method, Prof.do = Prof.do, functools.partial(Prof.do, obj=obj)
        yield
        # undo staticmethod modification
        Prof.do = staticmethod(saved_method)

    def decorator(fn):
        @functools.wraps(fn)
        def wrapped():
            obj = Prof(st)
            print 'current: obj.p is %r' % obj.p
            with prof_context(obj):
                fn()

        return wrapped

    return decorator

def do_p():
    Prof.do('do')

@wrapper('do_p2')
def do_p2():
    Prof.do('do2')

print '#A do_p():'
do_p()
print '#B do_p2():'
do_p2()
print '#C do_p():'
do_p()
print '#D do_p2():'
do_p2()
print '#E do_p():'
do_p()
print '#F do_p():'
do_p()
```

Output:

```
#A do_p():
s do

#B do_p2():
current: obj.p is 'do_p2'
do_p2 do2

#C do_p():
s do

#D do_p2():
current: obj.p is 'do_p2'
do_p2 do2

#E do_p():
s do

#F do_p():
s do
```

Comment: plz see this code https://gist.github.com/tywtyw2002/c885bd917430e0563288, why `C` print `do_p2do2 do` instead of `s do`. I want to the code like this if have decorator change the string with the argument in decorator, without decorator the string should remind the default value.

Comment: The problem is the class along with its static method are effectively global variables, and when you change the latter with `functools.partial()`, the last value assigned is used by all subsequent calls to it. If I come up with a solution I will update my answer.

Comment: See latest update which I think may accomplish what you want to do.